# How to redirect to a HTML page in CGI

Tags: html, perl

I am doing Perl and HTML programming with two files: `mainpage.html` and `mainpage.cgi`. I want let users input their username and password in text boxes, and if either of them is wrong, the page should stay the same and let user type again.

#### mainpage.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>User Login</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="http://localhost/cgi-bin/mainpage.cgi" method="post">
      Username: <input type="text" name="Username">  <br />
      Password: <input type="text" name="Password" />
      <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

#### mainpage.cgi

```
#!c:/Perl64/bin/perl.exe

local ( $buffer, @pairs, $pair, $Username, $Password, %FORM );

# Read information
$ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'} =~ tr/a-z/A-Z/;

if ( $ENV{'REQUEST_METHOD'} eq "POST" ) {
    read( STDIN, $buffer, $ENV{'CONTENT_LENGTH'} );
}
else {
    $buffer = $ENV{'QUERY_STRING'};
}

@pairs = split( /&/, $buffer );

foreach $pair ( @pairs ) {
    ( $Username, $Password ) = split( /=/, $pair );
    $Password =~ tr/+/ /;
    $Password =~ s/%(..)/pack("C", hex($1))/eg;
    $FORM{$Username} = $Password;
}
$Username = $FORM{Username};
$Password = $FORM{Password};

#Database
use DBI;
$dbh = DBI->connect( 'dbi:mysql:math_questions', 'root', 'admin' )
        or die "Connection Error: $DBI::errstr\n";

$sql = "select * FROM users where Username = '$Username' and Password = '$Password'";
$sth = $dbh->prepare( $sql );
$sth->execute or die "SQL Error: $DBI::errstr\n";
while ( @row = $sth->fetchrow_array ) {
    $user = $row[0];
    $key  = $row[1];
}

if ( $user ) {
    print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n";
    print "<html>";
    print "<head>";
    print '<meta charset="utf-8">';
    print '<title>math_questions</title>';
    print "</head>";
    print "<body>";
    print "<h2>Correct</h2>";
    print "</body>";
    print "</html>";
}
else {
    #I don't know how to do this part in a good way, thank you very much!
}

1;
```

Comment: There are a lot of issues in your Perl code. I think the tutorial you are using is not very good. And what you're doing with the password is just plain horrible. As for the part you want help with, your HTML document cannot display any errors. You can go back to the HTML file by redirecting, or by reading the file and having the Perl program output the content. But you will not be able to tell the user that their password was wrong and they should try again.

Comment: If you want to learn how web sites were developed in 1995 you're on the right track, but today you'd [`use CGI`](http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html) at the *absolute least* though a [framework](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_frameworks#Perl_2) would be *immeasurably better*.

Comment: **WARNING**: When writing SQL code use prepared statements with **placeholder values** and [never inject arbitrary user data into the query](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: **WARNING**: Do not store user passwords as plain-text. At the absolute least use something like [bcrypt](https://gist.github.com/evandrix/1076041) to properly hash them.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be learning Perl in the mid-1990s!

If you're determined to write this as a CGI program (and you shouldn't - it's 2016 and there are [far better alternatives](https://metacpan.org/pod/CGI::Alternatives)) then you should at least use some less outdated technologies.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use CGI qw[param header];
use DBI;
use Template;

my $tt = Template->new;
print header;

if (param) {
  # If we have parameters, then someone is trying to log in
  my $username = param('Username');
  my $password = param('Password');

  if (check_password($username, $password)) {
    # Password check succeeded. Display success page
    $tt->process('success.tt');
  } else {
    # Otherwise re-display initial form with an error message
    $tt->process('form.tt', { error => 'Please try again' });
  }
} else {
  # Otherwise display the initial form
  $tt->process('form.tt');
}

# NOTE: Storing passwords in plain text like this is a *terrible idea*!
sub check_password {
  my ($user, $pass) = @_;

  my $dbh = DBI->connect( 'dbi:mysql:math_questions', 'root', 'admin' )
    or die "Connection Error: $DBI::errstr\n";

  my $sql = 'select count(*)
             from   users
             where  Username = ? and Password = ?';

  my $sth = $dbh->prepare( $sql );
  $sth->execute($user, $pass) or die "SQL Error: $DBI::errstr\n";
  my $count = ($sth->fetchrow_array)[0];

  return $count;
}
```

You'll need two template files - one for the form and one for the success page. Bringing the form into the CGI program gives us the advantage that we can display an error message when people get the password wrong.

Here's `form.tt`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>User Login</title>
  </head>
  <body>
[% IF error -%]
    <p>[% error %]</p>
[% END -%]
    <form action="http://localhost/cgi-bin/mainpage.cgi" method="post">
      Username: <input type="text" name="Username">  <br />
      Password: <input type="text" name="Password" />
      <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here's `success.tt`:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>math_questions</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h2>Correct</h2>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
print "Content-type:text/html\r\n\r\n";
open(DATA, '<invaliduser.html') or die "invaliduser.html  $!"; 
while(<DATA>){
    print "$_";
}
```

Comment: Why not just redirect to the HTML page? And your Content-Type header will have invalid line endings if this is run on Windows.